# How to get a percentage from new Date();

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, clock, percentage

I have a digital clock for now, and I need the corn to know when 10 seconds as passed, this way it can go to the next frame.  Im having difficulty finding out how to gather the 10 secs and make it out of 100% for example
its 9:30:21 and i pushed the button
at 9:30:31 it should be done

but I want to create a percentage bar based on that 10sec.. heres my code

```
 farmSlot1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, farmClick1);


 var startTime: Date = new Date();
 var startSec: Number = startTime.seconds;





 function farmClick1(e: MouseEvent): void {
addChild(menu);
menu.x = 400;
menu.y = 90;
menu.buyCornBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buyCorn1);
 }

 function buyCorn1(e: MouseEvent): void {
var startTime: Date = new Date();
startSec = startTime.seconds;
menu.buyCornBtn.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, cornloading1);
farmSlot1.progressB.visible = true;
menu.buyCornBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buyCorn1);
removeChild(menu);
 }


function cornloading1(event: Event): void {
    var now: Date = new Date();
    var hr: Number = now.hours;
    var min: Number = now.minutes;
    var sec: Number = now.seconds;
    var finished: Number = startSec + 5
    var percent = Math.round((finished-sec) * 100)
    if(sec < finished){
    farmSlot1.loader_txt.text = percent
    Object(root).farmSlot1.progressB.bar.scaleX = percent;
    trace("hit");
    }else if (sec == finished && farmSlot1.currentLabel != "corn") {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, cornloading1);
        trace("It did it");
        farmSlot1.loader_txt.text = ""
        farmSlot1.gotoAndStop("corn");

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, as I see you are writing the code inside Flash frames. Incapsulating your code within classes is better approach which allows to avoid tons of problems in the future. Here is a link described some basic approaches for using classes:
http://www.kirupa.com/developer/as3/classes_as3_pg1.htm

In answer to your question:
You can simply use flash.utils.Timer class instead of using Date and ENTER_FRAME event: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html

Some piece of code:

```
//Import timer class
import flash.utils.Timer;

...

//In the class's body
//Create a timer instance. Timer will be executed 10 times every 100 milliseconds
private var timer:Timer = new Timer(100, 10);

...

//Somewhere in class's method (usually in the constructor)
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerCompleteHandler);

//Add click handler
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);
...

private function buttonClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //Do some stuff and start timer.
    timer.start();
}


private function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    //Update progress indicator
}

private function timerCompleteHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    //1 second is over so do some stuff.
}
```

Comment: Upd: I've just figured out you need 10 seconds instead of 1 minute so you should setup your timer using another values:

`private var timer:Timer = new Timer(100, 100)`

In this case you'll track your progress 10 times per second for 10 seconds.
Note that timer interval is restricted by current frame rate. Therefore, native AS3 timers become very unprecise when their interval is near to movie's framerate.

Comment: thats how I was doing it at first, but with 25spots, thats 25 timers.  I'm not sure how well mobile devices will handle that many timers. And since theres going to be about 9 items to plant do i have to make 225 timers To have unique instance names?

Comment: Anyway all the timers are based on ENTER_FRAME event. I guess you are able to use either Timer and ENTER_FRAME. Regarding to the implementation: create your own classes overriden from Sprite or MovieClip and put all the logic inside that classes (encapsulation). Your problem is that you are using frames for your code. Use classes and you'll be able to create a variable which won't be changed when you are jumping between frames. Are you working in Flash IDE?

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback.  I created a class like you said and it works wonders!  Thanks